# Prove non-linear system has unique solution

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

Assume $u > 1, p \in [0,1], \mu, \sigma$ are real numbers.
Prove that the system has a unique solution $(p,u)$: $$ pu + \frac{1-p}{u} = \mu$$ $$ pu^2 + \frac{1-p}{u^2} = \sigma^2 + \mu^2$$

### My attempt

I tried to square the first equation and subtract it from the second. The result was, after some cancellations, $$u^2 + \frac{1}{u^2} - 2p(1-p) = \sigma^2$$, which can be rewritten as a quadratic in $a = u^2$ : $$ a^2 - \frac{2p - 2p^2 + \sigma^2}{p(1-p)}a + 1 = 0$$ The determinant of this equation is always non-negative,  so it always has two roots. Moreover, if we denote $b = \frac{2p - 2p^2 + \sigma^2}{p(1-p)}$, we can see that $2b \geq \sqrt{b^2 - 4}$ so the equation has both roots positive. This is where I am stuck. I am not ever sure if this is the right approach. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

The system is equivalent to

$$\begin{cases}p(u^2-1)&=\mu u-1,\\p(u^2-1)(u^2+1)&=(\sigma^2+\mu^2)u^2-1.\end{cases}$$

Eliminating $p$, we have a cubic equation

$$\mu u^3-(\mu^2+\sigma^2+1)u^2-\mu u+2=0.$$

To prove that this equation has a single root $u>1$, you can evaluate the Sturm sequence of the polynomial at $u=1$ and $u=\infty$.

Comment: you've actually made a mistake: the final equation should be $u \mu^3 -(\mu^2 + \sigma^2 + 1)u^2 +\mu u = 0$ Then we can divide by u and we get a quadratic equation with coefficient $\mu$ in-front of $u^2$ and free coefficient $\mu$ so by Vieta's formulas the product of the roots is 1.